Prove that every finite measure is perfect
Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a countably generated measurable space. Then the following propositions are equivalent:

Every finite measure $\mu :\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$ is perfect;
There is a measurable function $h:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Sigma =\{h^{-1}(B):B\in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ and $h(X)$ is universally measurable.

My question is: how can I prove the implication $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$?

I found that proposition on page 89 of the book "Measure Theory Volume II" written by V.I. Bogachev. I don't think that the proof that this author gives is complete. Below, I will outline the proof and highlight the problem.
The proof author uses the following results:

(A) Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Every Borel measure on
$\mathfrak{B}(X)$ is perfect if and only if $X$ is universally
measure.
(B) Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. If for every
measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, the set $f(X)$ is universally
measurable, then every finite measure $\mu:\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$ is
perfect. Conversely, if every measure on every countably generated
sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_0\subseteq\Sigma$ is perfect, then for
every measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, the set $f(X)$ is
universally measurable.

Suppose the item (2) is true.
Let $\mu:\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ be any finite measure and $f:X\to \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$ be any measurable function.
Because of the result (B), to finish the proof it's sufficient to prove that $f(X)$ is universally measurable.
Using the Doob-Dynkin Lemma we can show that there's a measurable function $g:h(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g\circ h$.
The author says: "According to (A) every Borel measure on $h(X)$ is perfect. By (B) the set $g(h(X))$ is universally measurable." But to use (B) to conclude that $g(h(X))$ is universally measurable, you need to show that every finite measure on every countably generated sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathfrak{B}(h(X))$ is  perfect.
Trying to understand the proof of (B), I realized that we can conclude that $g(h(X))$ is universally measurable from the fact the every Borel measure on $h(X)$ is perfect if $\{g^{-1}(B):B\in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\}=\{B\cap h(X):B\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$. But I don't see why this holds in the general case.
We'd be able to complete the proof if we could extend the result (A) in the following way: Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Every Borel measure on $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ is perfect iff $X$ is universally measurable iff $g(X)$ universally measurable for all measurable function $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$. But I don't know if this is true.

If $\Sigma$ separates the points of $X$ and (2) holds then $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(h(X),\mathfrak{B}(h(X)))$ are isomorphic. Then (1) follows from (A). So is the question what to do if $\Sigma$ does not separate the points of $X$? In that case one can combine the points that are not separated and get an almost isomorphic space. (B) is not needed.

@user95282 could you please write an answer with more detail? I didn’t understand the part about getting an almost isomorphic space.

'@rfloc If $\Sigma$ does not separate the points of $X$, we may collapse every set of points that are not separated into a single point. That does not change measurable functions from $X$, nor measures on $(X,\Sigma)$. More formally, measurable functions from the collapsed space define measurable functions on the original space in a natural one-to-one fashion, and similarly for measures on $(X,\Sigma)$.

The sufficiency part of Theorem (B) requires proving that the image $f(X)$ of every measurable function $f: X \to\Bbb R$ is universally measurable. Knowing that the image $h(X)$ of a specific function $h$ is universally measurable is insufficient for direct application of Theorem (B).
While it is true that $\{g^{-1}(B) : B \in \mathfrak{B}(\Bbb R)\}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathfrak{B} (h(X))$, it is generally a proper sub-$\sigma$-algebra. It contains only those subsets of $h(X)$ that can be expressed as the pre-image under $g$ of Borel sets in $\Bbb R$. It does not necessarily encompass all possible intersections of Borel sets in $\Bbb R$ with $h(X)$.

I just saw on the book "Measure Theory" by Fremlin that the extension of the result (A) that I proposed is true. I'm trying to prove it. With it I will be able to prove that implication.
